# Rails 5: Saving external API call to DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm currently trying to save filled out forms from my Typeform. Everything works just fine, except when I try to save the form to the `db`.

My model `Order.rb`

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
    include HTTParty
    base_uri 'api.typeform.com'

    def initialize
      token = '############################'
      @auth = 'Bearer ' + token
    end

    def get_orders
      response = self.class.get("/forms/######/responses?page_size=25", headers: { "Authorization" => @auth})
    end

    def save_orders
      if response.code.to_i == 200
        orders = response.parsed_response
        order = response["items"]
        order.each do |data|
          create!(
            email: data["hidden"]["email"]
          )
        end
      else
        raise "Error fetching data from Typeform API"
      end
    end

end
```

Comment: Hi Arnas,
Are you familiar with Typeform webhook?
https://developer.typeform.com/webhooks/

That might be an easier thing to implement.

You also give more details of the error you get.

Comment: Hey there! Unfortunaetly nothing is happening... I'm not even getting any errors in the console.

Comment: @ArnasKlasauskas try just disabling `belongs_to :user`, and try again! Do not forget to restart server! I think, u need to pass `user_id` also.

Comment: You question is not clear what exactly is working and what not. When do you call `get_orders`. Where do you use result returned by `get_orders`? When you call `save_orders`? These are pointer questions to make you think aloud what's the problem.

Comment: I already solved it by myself. Sorry, for making the question not clear!